# How to change the text of button?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

How to change the text of button on the first click? Now it takes two clicks to change the text:

```
int countt1 = 3;
var buttonn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonn1);

buttonn1.Click += (sender, e)=>
{
    if (countt1 >= 0)
        buttonn1.Text = string.Format("{0}", countt2--);
};
```

Comment: Remove `if (countt1 >= 0)`

Comment: but countt1 must not be less than 0

Comment: As SushiHangover wrote. If you want to change the text immediately than you need to remove `if (count>=0)`.

Comment: countt1 is already initialized to 3, so the if won't matter.  I suspect the problem is the post-decrement of countt2, but can't say for sure without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jason points out, using the postfix decrement operator (countt2--) gives the value before the decrement occurs. For the value after the decrement occurs, change to the prefix decrement operator like this:

```
    buttonn1.Text = string.Format("{0}", --countt2);
```

[C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx).

Comment: OMG! it's works thank you so so much i've been searching for two weeks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  const oldText="BUTTON TAG TEXT";
  document.write(
    '<button id=butId onClick="changeText(this.id)">'+oldText+'</button>'
  );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
const stat=[oldText,"NEW BUTTON TAG TEXT"];
let   cptr=0;

function changeText(button_id){
   var el = document.getElementById(button_id);

   el.textContent = stat[cptr^=1];

// or       el.firstChild.data = stat[cptr^=1];

// or       el.innerHTML = stat[cptr^=1];
}
</script>
```